# rails bootstrap helper function 't'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When scaffolding rails views to bootstrap, it creates nice buttons with link_to functions as follows:

```
<%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
              edit_user_path(@user), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
```

What does the function '**t(...)**' exactly do, and why is it so voluminous? I know I could skip it, but wondering about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 't' is the translate method of the rails I18N internationalization.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html